# Error in 1:nrow(SM) : argument of length 0 for metadata file

Tags: r

Good day everyone

I am really struggling to get my metadata file in Rstudio for analysis. The import of the file is working perfectly fine, however, the moment I am trying to generate a phyloseq object this is the error I am getting: Error in 1:nrow(SM): argument of length 0.

My code:

```
# This is to import the file into Rstudio
metadata_ASV = read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE, row.names = 1, sep = "\t")
```

I then check the form of the file

```
class(metadata_ASV)
```

The command below is the one I am using to generate the phyloseq object. This command did work previously but suddenly it is not working anymore.

```
ASV_sampledata = sample_data(metadata_ASV)
```

Any insight into what is causing the error:

> Error in 1:nrow(SM): argument of length 0

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Regards
Sunette

Comment: Run `str(metadata_ASV)`. Possibly your data was overwritten.